# "bad magic error" when struct included by pickle.py

Tags: python, python-packaging, pyenv, pyc, uncompyle6

I'm tring to uncompile `pyc` files by `uncompyle6` when the scripts running with error occuring:

```
PS E:\Downloads\WhoAmI.exe_extracted> python unc.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Downloads\WhoAmI.exe_extracted\unc.py", line 1, in <module>
    import uncompyle6
  File "C:\pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.10.5\lib\site-packages\uncompyle6\__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
    from uncompyle6.semantics import fragments, pysource
  File "C:\pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.10.5\lib\site-packages\uncompyle6\semantics\fragments.py", line 70, in <module>
    from uncompyle6.semantics import pysource
  File "C:\pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.10.5\lib\site-packages\uncompyle6\semantics\pysource.py", line 136, in <module>
    from spark_parser import GenericASTTraversal
  File "C:\pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.10.5\lib\site-packages\spark_parser\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from spark_parser.spark import DEFAULT_DEBUG
  File "C:\pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.10.5\lib\site-packages\spark_parser\spark.py", line 25, in <module>
    import os, pickle, re, sys
  File "C:\pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.10.5\lib\pickle.py", line 33, in <module>
    from struct import pack, unpack
ImportError: bad magic number in 'struct': b'\xe3\x00\x00\x00'
```

At first I thought it's because of the lack of magic number in the `pyc` file I was uncompiling but the problem still exists after the magic number was added. I tried to create simple scripts which just import packages and print `Hello, world!` and then uncompile the `pyc` file generated but the same error occured.

Cleaning the `__pycache__` folder on my project or where `pickle.py` is does not work.

Reinstalling `uncompyle6` or `spark_parser` does not work.

Switching the version of Python (3.9.0 and 3.10.5) by `pyenv` does not work. So I regard it as a general problem.

Thus, I tried to run `from struct import pack` on the interactive environment and the problem still exists.